# Ruby: How to concatenate array of arrays into one

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I have an array of arrays in Ruby on Rails (3.1) where all the internal arrays are of different size. Is there a way to easily concatenate all the internal arrays to get one big one dimesional array with all the items?

I know you can use the Array::concat function to concatenate two arrays, and I could do a loop to concatenate them sequentially like so:

```
concatenated = Array.new
array_of_arrays.each do |array|
    concatenated.concat(array)
end
```

but I wanted to know if there was like a Ruby one-liner which would do it in a cleaner manner.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As suggested, `flatten(1)` is what you want, but I wanted to point out that you could write what you have above as `array_of_arrays.reduce(:concat)`.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You're looking for [`#flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten):

```
concatenated = array_of_arrays.flatten
```

By default, this will flatten the lists recursively. `#flatten` accepts an optional argument to limit the recursion depth – the documentation lists examples to illustrate the difference.

Comment: Better `flatten(1)`. Elements in array could be array themselves and they would be recursively flattened.

Comment: the optional argument requires Ruby 1.8.7 or higher by the way

Comment: Also as a general suggestion; it would be recommended to use `flatten!(n)` as this modifies the object in place instead of making a copy of it. Using methods that alter objects in place can be more performant by reducing the amount of GC needed to be done.

Comment: 1. This is pretty potent necromancy :D 2. I wouldn't make it a *general* recommendation, especially now that functional programming is a meme. But even disregarding that, I'd argue that *generally* clobbering inputs bad, referential transparency good, and one should use bang methods as an optimization where the observable result is the same as if you used a copy unless you have program logic based reasons to want to expose the in-place mutation.

Answer (score 30):

Or more generally:

```
array_of_arrays.reduce(:concat)
```

Comment: This will not destroy 3, 4 or 5+ dimensional arrays in the way that flatten will ;)  With `#flatten`, you need to be very aware of what your arrays contain, as it is a recursive method, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll keep that in mind when I use it for something like that. In this case it wasn't very important, as they were simple arrays and recursive works fine.

Comment: @d11wtq: that's true, that why Ruby 1.9 has `flatten(n)`

Comment: Note that this code will alter the original `array_of_arrays` which could cause issues if you still plan to use the original array elsewhere.

Comment: To avoid altering the original, you can do `array_of_arrays.reduce :+`.  But note that both of these return `nil` if `array_of_arrays` is empty, whereas `flatten` returns `[]`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use flatten! method. eg.
`a = [ 1, 2, [3, [4, 5] ] ]
a.flatten!   #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: By using `a.flatten!` you also prevent making a duplicate of the array, saving memory and garbage collection.